# install nodejs socketio package

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to install NodeJS with socket.io. I tried different ways to install, but none are working. I installed from tar.gz, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
pedram@ubuntu:/var/tmp$ npm install socketio.tar.gz
npm WARN package.json socket.io@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN excluding symbolic link client/socket.io.js -> ../node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io/0.4.3
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io/0.4.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io/-/engine.io-0.4.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 408 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/-/socket.io-parser-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io/-/engine.io-0.4.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/-/socket.io-parser-1.0.2.tgz
npm WARN package.json socket.io-parser@1.0.2 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client
```

The terminal freezes here, it seems that I have Internet problem at that line, do you have any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: tried the normal way?
npm install socket.io
?

Comment: also please provide more data about OS/platform

Comment: Hi , I have did that well , It takes 30 minutes to install that npm and done , but I have a questioon , for client side socket.io.js , I have to that from server with src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js" , I have included that file to client but that not work , do you know how to fix that

Comment: Do you have nginx or any software between the client and your node server that sends static assets to the client?

Comment: I have apache and it send file

Comment: Then you have a problem. Apache tries to load the file located at `<your_public_dir>/socket.io/socket.io.js`, when in fact, the socket.io.js file is located inside the `node_modules/socket.io` directory. You have to configure apache to forward the request to the node app. The high level algorithm is something like this: if (url == "socket.io/socket.io.js") forward to node.js app; else if (url == something ended in .js, .css, etc) send public asset; else forward request to node.js app;

Comment: There is a file you can pull out of the NPM and host on the front end in this path: socket.io / node_modules / socket.io-client / dist / socket.io.js

Comment: yes , and it seem not working . also another question , I have heared socket.io reaLtime is not working on Internet explorer , is it true ?